# Selinium 2.53.1 - PHP Acceptance test - click javascript alert

Tags: symfony, acceptance-testing

I have a problem. I would like to test a page and on the page has a link.
When i clicked it I see javascript alert. 
Question:
How i can to click the OK?

I work in Symfomy 2.4, codecept 2.0.7 and selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1, firefox webdriver
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you set key press on enter?

$this->driver->getKeyboard()->pressKey('ENTER')

Comment: Thanks the idea, i solved my problem with acceptPopup command.